# Tab bar item frame bug?

Tags: button, frame, subview, tabbar

Hello I have a problem with TabBar
I would like to get the frame of a UITabBarItem in a UITabBar, in the past (swift 2) I got the result using :
`let frame = self.tabBar.subviews.last?.frame`
Now (swift 3) the same command I get a frame that does not have the width of any of UITabBarItem frame.
In particular I tried to print the subviews of `self.tabBar`
using the code below:

```
    for i in self.tabBar.subviews{
        print(i)
    }
```

obtaining this result:

[image]

instead seeing the debug view it is clear that the subviews of UITabBar are 3 (_UIBarBackground, UITabBarButton, UITabBarButton).
And if I print the description it is clear that they are different.

[image]

any suggestions ? I forgotten anything?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to get the frame of a UITabBarItem

You cannot. A UITabBarItem is not a UIView. It has no frame.

Comment: UITabBarButton has the frame properties prove it prints:

Comment: UITabBarButton is a private unknown class. It is not the same as UITabBarItem.